# Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphKeys'

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorlayer

I'm currently trying to get a chatbot running with tensorflow.
The example for the chatbot is from this repository:
[Github](https://github.com/tensorlayer/seq2seq-chatbot)

I ran into some issues when I tried to run this in my tensorflow docker container.
When starting the script the script exits with an Attribute Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorlayer as tl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorlayer/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorlayer import initializers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorlayer/initializers.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorlayer.layers.core import LayersConfig
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorlayer/layers/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .activation import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorlayer/layers/activation.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorlayer.layers.core import Layer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorlayer/layers/core.py", line 39, in <module>
    TF_GRAPHKEYS_VARIABLES = tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GraphKeys'
```

I'm using the following Versions:

> tensorflow                    2.0.0a0
>   tensorlayer                   1.11.1

Maybe some of you had already a similar issue and knows how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using `pip install tensorflow==1.13.2`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tl mismatch tf, you need to update your tensorlayer to 2.0+.you can use this instruction：

```
pip3 install https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/archive/master.zip
```